# Put JavaScript variable into PHP with AJAX?

Tags: biztalk-mapper

Here's a some of my JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
    var finalMove = "a1";
    $.post("index.php", {postFinalMove:finalMove});
];
```

Here is my PHP code. The commented lines are just two of the things I've tried.

```
<?php
session_start();

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","myUsername","myPassword","abraDB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}

//if (isset($_POST['postFinalMove']))
//{
//  $turn = ($db, $_POST['postFinalMove']);     
//  echo $turn;
//}

//if ($_POST['postFinalMove'])
//{
//  $turn = ($db, $_POST['postFinalMove']);     
//  echo $turn;
//}     

if ($_POST['logout'])
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

As soon as I uncomment some of the code I've tried, my entire webpage is blank with no errors and no source code, which makes this hard for me to debug. Javascript function fires just fine, its my index.php page that crashes. PHP code was working great until this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `$turn = ($db,$_POST['postFinalMove']);` ? That's pretty unusual syntax. I don't think it's valid, but it could just be something I've never seen before.

Comment: this cause the error `$turn = ($db, $_POST['postFinalMove']);`

Comment: $db is an object so echoing it why?

Comment: If you just want to be sure the variable is sent, just do `echo $_POST['postFinalMove'];`

Comment: you must also on `display_errors` in your php.ini

Comment: And just as the other members said that the `$turn` variable line is pretty much unusual as it's not making any sense that what you are trying to do in there??? :D

Comment: Replace your `$turn` line with this one as and then try again : `$turn = $_POST['postFinalMove'];`

Comment: Also make sure that you have `display_errors = on`  in your `php.ini` or if not so then add this code at the start of your php file and then try again and let us know if you get any error as : `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: is `myFunction` called as a result of a form submit?

Comment: Please before posting question here in `SO` please make sure on your end that the question is just not some syntax issue related question so the members time is not wasted here on such questions..Always take a close look on your code and alongside googling will also help like more than 90% to help you out with your issue and also to let you know how to properly write code..! :D I hope you won't mind it..!

Comment: it's not polite to ignore people's comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the following in your PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['postFinalMove'])){
   echo $_POST['postFinalMove'];
}
```

This line is probably causing the error:

```
//  $turn = ($db, $_POST['postFinalMove']);
```

That statement does not make any sense. What are you trying to store in `$turn`? If you want to store the `$_POST['postFinalMove']` you would have:

```
$turn = $_POST['postFinalMove'];
```

Comment: Okay thanks for mocking me guys lol I had a functioning login and registration code block so I just kind of copied and pasted a section from that knowing that it probably wouldn't work but youtube/stack overflow didn't offer me much guidance. I'll delete this question soon before I get bullied more.

Comment: @Jacobjanak : No offence Dear..May have even happened to us even in the start but it's OK..I appreciate your enthusiasm that you are trying to ask for help which is mostly not the case when it comes to lots of people..! So no offence again..!

Comment: I think the real thing to take away here would be to get your error logging / display working (see the original question comments). It will save you lots of headaches in the future!

Comment: Yea thanks for that tip.. I've been using cPanel's text editor instead of my own IDE for my very short php code since it was the easiest way (oops)

Comment: Regarding `cPanel` as I think normally the `display_errors = on` but if in your case the errors are off so then you can do exactly just as I said in the above comment to be able to see errors in future..! :D

Comment: Text editors are one thing but you should have settings in your `php.ini` file that will enable/disable error logging and error displaying on the actual site. If you don't know where your `php.ini` file is you can always run `phpinfo()` on one of your pages. Load that page and it should tell you which `php.ini` file is being loaded. Also checkout: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the **GIF** image and you will see for yourself..!

[image]

Replace your code with this line as and you are good to go then :

```
$turn = $_POST['postFinalMove']; 
  echo $turn;
```

It's just a simple **Syntax Issue** nothing more than that Dear..! :D